# Убрать внизу родителя пустое место, образовавшееся после смещения дочернего блока вверх

Tags: css, css3

Есть следующая разметка и стили - [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/bjd9pnw3/)

```
 <div class="parentBlock">
  <div class="upperBlock">Content of upper block</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="childBlock">
    Content of child
  </div>
</div>


.parentBlock, .childBlock, .upperBlock {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.upperBlock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.childBlock {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

В родителе внизу образовалась пустота.

Можно ли с помощью [css](/questions/tagged/css) убрать пустоту?
Т.е. ожидаемый результат [image: Ожидаемый результат]
 Жёстко задавать `height` у родителя не вариант, т.к. пользователь может менять ширину окна браузера

Comment: Дайте весь код и все стили которые затрагивают эти два блока плюс то что у вас под стилем * {}

Comment: Поправил описание и сделал ссылку на пример

Comment: Если не трудно добавьте картинку как оно должно выглядеть.

Comment: добавил в описание картинку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените в классе `.childBlock` стиль `top: -100px;` на `margin-top: -100px;`

```css
.parentBlock, .childBlock, .upperBlock {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.upperBlock {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.childBlock {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div class="parentBlock">
  <div class="upperBlock">Content of upper block</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="childBlock">
    Content of child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Алексей, гениально и просто). Спасибо!